# int.TryParse in U-SQL

Tags: c#, u-sql

I am trying to validate if a string variable in a U-SQL SELECT can be interpreted as an integer, som I am trying to use int.TryParse to replace "0" and "" with default value of two and everything above 10 with 10. Here is the code:

```
DECLARE @maxAvgkWh double = 100.00;
DECLARE @defaultM2 int = 90;
DECLARE @defaultPersons int = 2;


// Extracting installations and their information
@forDecisionTree =
    EXTRACT [InstallationId] string,
            [PrimaryHeatingType] string,
            [Persons] string,
            [SquareMeters] string,
            [LatestAvgDailykWh] double
    FROM "adl://some text file in azure data lake"
    USING Extractors.Tsv(skipFirstNRows : 1, silent : true);


// Making sure that NULLS and zeroes and abnormal values are replaced with default values
@forDecisionTreeHouseTypeReplNulls =
    SELECT  [InstallationId],
            [PrimaryHeatingType],
            (
                ! int.TryParse(Persons, out var _pers) || _pers <= 0 ?  
                    @defaultPersons :
                    _pers > 10 ?
                        10 :
                        _pers
            ).ToString() AS [Persons],
            (
                ! int.TryParse([SquareMeters], out var _m2) || _m2 <= 0 ?  
                    @defaultM2 :
                    _m2 > 500 ?
                        500 :
                        _m2
            ).ToString() AS [SquareMeters],
            [LatestAvgDailykWh]
    FROM @forDecisionTreeHouseType
    WHERE [LatestAvgDailykWh] < @maxAvgkWh;
```

I keep getting the following error:

> C# error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected
>
> at token '_pers', line 108 near the ###:
>
> ---
>
> ...! int.TryParse([Persons], out var  ### _pers) || _pers <= 0 ?  ...

Comment: Can you show the full query ?

Comment: I have updated the code so please find more details now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TryParse` is not one of the functions you can call directly.  It has to be wrapped as an inline function.  A simple example:

```
@output =
    SELECT FirstName,
               (
                (Func<string, int?>)
                (inputString =>  // input_paramater
                    { 
                        int outputValue;
                        return int.TryParse(inputString, out outputValue) ? (int?)outputValue : (int?)null;
                    }
                 )
            ) (Salary) AS someDate

    FROM @Employees;
```

Examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/ddl/functions) and [here](https://sqlplayer.net/2017/10/functions-in-the-usql-the-hidden-gem-in-the-summer-2017-update/).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks wBob for the input. I managed to write something that works and replaces empty strings and default values to out of range numbers based on your input. Here is the final code:

```
DECLARE @defaultPersons int = 2;

@forDecisionTreeHouseTypeReplNulls =
    SELECT  [InstallationId],
            [Persons],
                (   
                (Func<string, int?>)
                (inputString => // input_parameter
                    {
                        int _pers;
                        return ! int.TryParse([Persons], out _pers) || _pers <= 0 ?
                            @defaultPersons :
                            _pers > 10 ?
                                10 :
                                    _pers;
                    }
                )
             ) ([Persons]) AS [AdjPersons]
```